# How do I create an in memory persistence store for Windows Workflow 4 State Machines?

Tags: persistence, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I've written a state machine using Windows Workflow 4 which has a number of states which contains  bookmarks which I use to resume processing from one state to another. Whilst idle I want to persist the state machine state and spin it up again at a later date (potentially weeks ahead in the future).

My state machine requires a series of services (interface injected) to be supplied as 'in-arguments' at run-time and also an instance of a 'state tracker' class which keeps track of pertinent variables the state machine would need to persist and recover. The properties of the state class are simple types like dates, enums and numbers.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
var store = new InMemoryPersistentStore(new StateObject() { State = "Pending", Value = 10 );
var workflowInstance = factory.ResumeFrom(store);
workflowInstance.DoSomething(); // From existing restored state.
```

I'd expect to be able to recreate the workflow instance recovered to a state without having to persist the whole structure of the workflow in XML. The out of the box persistence store is very rigid in its requirements such as all objects internally needing to be serializable which is not practical for me.

I've also read about StateMachineStateTracker and it's neighbouring class StateTrackerPersistenceProvider which are elusive in their documentation (these come from System.Activities.Extensions for other readers) but these seem to also rely on the out of the box Sql Persistence store which again seems massively over-weight.

I can't seem to find examples that show any degree of detail about this process or how to work around it. I've reviewed the sample MS documentation which serializes each of the instance values to XML and back again but this seems like massive overkill to me (and as I said not possible for me) and also fraught with (what I believe to be) versioning issues in the future.

Is there a way, a simple way preferably, that I can spin up my workflow from memory into a state based on my supplied injected state class instance? I have considered placing a state transitions at the start of the workflow to 'hop' to the appropriate initial state based on my class, but this seems very un-elegant and very un-statemachine like to me and I'd much prefer to avoid it. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I have done similar (with regular workflows and not state machines) I have persisted the workflow to the regular persistence store without persisting the injected 'state tracker' and then persisted the 'state tracker' to a different, more suitable, database.
Later you can then resume the workflow from the store which places the execution point at the point it was stored and re-inject the 'state tracker' class.